# Access, Relationship. Too complicated Syntax?

Tags: ms-access

I am working on an assignment for school, building a database of games from a video game company. I have to have a relationship between the gameID, and the reviews. it is supposed to give me the reviews in my Gametable. Unfortunately it is not showing as I had expected it to. I cannot figure out whats going on.

Included are the screens for both design, and datasheet for both tables, and the relationship built between them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried googling for answers with no luck, I have destroyed and recreated the relationships with various different joins. No matter what this is what I end up getting:

[image]

I have also of course clicked this link it gives and tried to understand what's happening from there but I just don't understand it.

If someone could either point me in the right direction, or just point out what I am missing. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Next step is to create a Query with both tables.  Go to Create then use Query Wizard.  when you add both tables teh relationship (join) should happen automatically.  if not, just join them.

Comment: yip, gameID is autonumber in VanillaWare and text in Reviews.  Usually you want gameID to be Autonumber in VanillaWare (1) and long in Reviews(many)  avoid fixing it to text in both.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally, It was my Game ID's were set to Auto Numbers along with a few other items. Access had trouble figuring out what to do.